# merge two map[string]interface{} from json

Tags: json, dictionary, go, interface

I have two json inputs built this way

```
"count: 1 result: fields"
```

I would like to concatenate the fields that I find within result without using a defined structure. I have tried in many ways but most of the time the result is an error about the type Interface {} or the last map overwritten the data

I would like both the "result" and the first and second map fields to be merged within the result in output.

```
oracle, err := http.Get("http://XXX:8080/XXXX/"+id)
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
defer oracle.Body.Close()

mysql, err := http.Get("http://XXX:3000/XXX/"+id)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
defer mysql.Body.Close()

oracleJSON, err := ioutil.ReadAll(oracle.Body)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
mysqlJSON, err := ioutil.ReadAll(mysql.Body)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}

var oracleOUT map[string]interface{}
var mysqlOUT map[string]interface{}

json.Unmarshal(oracleJSON, &oracleOUT)
json.Unmarshal(mysqlJSON, &mysqlOUT)

a := oracleOUT["result"]
b := mysqlOUT["result"]


c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"result": ????})
```

this is an example of json

```
{"count":1,"result":{"COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636","MATRICOLA":"60636","COGNOME":"PIPPO"}}
```

If i have two json like this the result of the function it should be

```
`"result":{"COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636","MATRICOLA":"60636","COGNOME":"PIPPO","COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636","MATRICOLA":"60636","COGNOME":"PIPPO"}}`
```

Comment: Give us JSON example please

Comment: {"count":1,"result":{"COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636","MATRICOLA":"60636","COGNOME":"PIPPO"}}

this is the JSON example. If i have two json like this the result of the function it should be

"result":{"COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636","MATRICOLA":"60636","COGNOME":"PIPPO","COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636","MATRICOLA":"60636","COGNOME":"PIPPO"}}

Comment: Your output as described is not valid JSON.  You describe "result" as referring to an object by using brackets, but objects are *SETS* which means names may not be repeated. Is it preferable to you to reformat the output to be valid JSON, or to maintain the structure despite the fact it is not JSON?  I can provide an answer either way, but need to know which you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are looking for is not valid JSON. However with a small change you can output something very similar to your example that is valid JSON.

You probably do want to use a defined structure for the portion of the input that has a known structure, so that you can extract the more abstract "result" section more easily.

If you start at the top of the input structure using a `map[string]interface{}` then you'll have to do a type assertion on the "result" key. For example:

```
var input map[string]interface{}

err = json.Unmarshal(data, &input)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
keys, ok := input["result"].(map[string]interface{})
if !ok {
    return errors.New("wasn't the type we expected")
}
```

However if you used a defined structure for the top level you can do it like the following which feels much cleaner.

```
type Input struct {
    Count  int                    `json:"count"`
    Result map[string]interface{} `json:"result"`
}

var input Input
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &input)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// from here you can use input.Result directly without a type assertion
```

To generate output that has duplicate keys, you could use an array of objects with a single key/value pair in each, then you end up with a valid JSON structure that does not overwrite keys.  Here's how to do that ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/ZPrDeFlX3Vu)):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Input struct {
    Count  int                    `json:"count"`
    Result map[string]interface{} `json:"result"`
}

type Output struct {
    Count  int                      `json:"count"`
    Result []map[string]interface{} `json:"result"`
}

var inputdata = [][]byte{
    []byte(`{"count":1,"result":{"COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636", "MATRICOLA":"60636", "COGNOME":"PIPPO"}}`),
    []byte(`{"count":1,"result":{"COD_DIPENDENTE":"00060636", "MATRICOLA":"60636", "COGNOME":"PIPPO"}}`),
}

func main() {
    inputs := make([]Input, len(inputdata))
    for i := range inputs {
        err := json.Unmarshal(inputdata[i], &inputs[i])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    var out Output
    out.Count = len(inputs)
    for _, input := range inputs {
        for k, v := range input.Result {
            out.Result = append(out.Result, map[string]interface{}{k: v})
        }
    }

    outdata, _ := json.Marshal(out)
    fmt.Println(string(outdata))
}
```

Which produces output that looks like this when formatted:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "result": [
    {"MATRICOLA": "60636"},
    {"COGNOME": "PIPPO"},
    {"COD_DIPENDENTE": "00060636"},
    {"COGNOME": "PIPPO"},
    {"COD_DIPENDENTE": "00060636"},
    {"MATRICOLA": "60636"}
  ]
}
```